# Update point fields with fields in intersecting polygon

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-3

I get new points (inspections) every day. Each point falls within a polygon (district).
I need to update 3 fields (Week, RecycleRt, RecyCollDay) in the point feature class with the district fields.
[image: Districts and inspections]

I did some research and found a script that does something similar to what I need.
So modified the script in answer to this post [Selecting points within polygon and updating attributes using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115087)

Here's my script:

```
import arcpy, os


arcpy.env.workspace = "\\\\Projects\\RecyclingAudit\\RecyclingAuditUpdate"
PW = "\\\\Projects\\RecyclingAudit\\RecyclingAuditUpdate\\UpdateAudits.gdb"
RecyDistrict = "\\\\connections\\SDELOAD@Pub.sde\\RecyclingDistrict"
RecyAudit = PW +"\\RecyclingAudit"
RecyAuditFieldList = ["Week","RecycleRt","RecyCollDay"]
SpatialJoin = PW + "\\SpatialJoin_RA"
SpatialJoinFields = ["Week", "RecycleRt", "RecyCollDay"]

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Delete scratch spatial join feature
if arcpy.Exists(SpatialJoin):
    arcpy.Delete_management(SpatialJoin)

# Scratch spatial join feature
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(RecyAudit, RecyDistrict, SpatialJoin, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL",
                           'Crdt "Crdt" false true false 8 Date 0 0,First,#,RecyclingAudit,Crdt,-1,-1;'
                           'Address1 "address" true true false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,RecyclingAudit,Address1,0,255;'
                           'Classification "Classification" true true false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,RecyclingAudit,Classification,0,255;'
                           'Status "Status" true true false 10 Text 0 0,First,#,RecyclingAudit,Status,0,10;'
                           'Compliance "Compliance" true true false 5 Text 0 0,First,#,RecyclingAudit,Compliance,0,5;'
                           'Week "Week" true true false 50 Text 0 0,First,#,SolidWasteRecyclingDistrict,Week,0,50;'
                           'RecycleRt "RecycleRt" true true false 50 Text 0 0,First,#,SolidWasteRecyclingDistrict,RecycleRt,0,50;'
                           'RecyCollDay "RecyCollDay" true true false 50 Text 0 0,First,#,SolidWasteRecyclingDistrict,RecyCollDay,0,50',
                           "INTERSECT", None, '')

   
# Start edit session
# arcpy.env.workspace doesn't work
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(PW)
edit.startEditing(True, False)
edit.startOperation()

# Populate the dictionary from recycling district
valueDict = {r[0]:(r[1:]) for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SpatialJoin, SpatialJoinFields)}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(RecyAudit, RecyAuditFieldList) as updateRows:
    for updateRow in updateRows:
        keyValue = updateRow[0]
        if keyValue in valueDict:
            for n in range (1,len(SpatialJoinFields)):
                updateRow = valueDict[keyValue][n-1]
            updateRows.updateRow(updateRow)
    del valueDict


# Stop edit operation, stop edit session and save changes
edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "X:/Scripts/Python/TEST/ShortRecyclingAuditUpdate.py", line 45, in
>
> updateRows.updateRow(updateRow) TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row

How can I fix this error? This is the first time I work with da.UpdateCursor and I don't understand exactly how it works.
I think for this to work correctly it needs to match Crdt (create date) field on both feature classes. If it finds a match, then it should update the fields.

Comment: It's pretty confusing having `updateRow` (list), `updateRows` (cursor), `updateRow` (string), and `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor.updateRow` (method) all in one code block (this is the source of your error as well).  Your code would be better self-documenting if you used `row`, `cursor`, and `value` for the names over which you have control, then you would see that `cursor.updateRow(value)` doesn't meet the first parameter expectation of a list of length (`len(RecyAuditFieldList)`).  Also, best practice is to restrict uppercase names to classes.

Comment: Not sure, but this answer I provided might be useful for you... somewhat related to what you're trying to do (I think...)  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/87055/18630

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the error. I had to add a common field to both field lists (RecyAuditFieldList and SpatialJoinFields) which are OBJECTID and TARGET_FID.
The edited list looks like this:

```
RecyAuditFieldList = ["OID@","Week","RecycleRt","RecyCollDay"]
SpatialJoinFields = ["TARGET_FID","Week", "RecycleRt", "RecyCollDay"]
```

Comment: Those changes won't fix the error in the message.